# Is there a way to hide autodoc of exceptions and save methods?

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm documenting a huge Django project and would like to have an option to hide autogenerated Django stuff like below. Is it something I have to "deal with" or is there a setting I haven't found yet?

I document with:

```
.. automodule:: module.models
    :members:
```

and get things like below, which would be good if I had those overriden, but they're not:

```
exception DoesNotExist

exception MultipleObjectsReturned

save(*args, **kwargs):...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation of [`automodule` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-automodule) and its options, including `exclude-members`:

> The directives supporting member documentation also have a
> `exclude-members` option that can be used to exclude single member
> names from documentation, if all members are to be documented.

### Update for Sphinx >= 1.8

HT to @nerdoc in comments.

[`autodoc_default_flags` is deprecated in Sphinx 1.8](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#id1284).

It has been moved into a new setting [`autodoc_default_options`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options) as an option.

```
autodoc_default_options = {
    "exclude-members": "__weakref__",
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `:exlude-members: DoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned` worked miracles.

Comment: `autodoc_default_flags` is deprecated since v1.8 andIntegrated into [autodoc_default_options](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options)